# iOS: pushViewController does not create a custom nav bar in the new view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I've created a custom `UINavigationBar`-derived class (MyNavBar), and would like to use it as the nav bar for my app. I set the `MyNavBar` class on the `nav` bar element in the `XIB`, and also set a custom `MyNavItem` class on the `nav` item in the XIB. This works well for the first view controller in my `nav controller`.

But when I call `pushViewController`, the newly-pushed `controller` does not seem to use the custom nav bar item. And for a good reason: I don't know where I can tell the `nav controller` that it should create a custom nav bar item for every pushed controller... so I guess it creates a `UINavigationItem` object instead...

Any idea how to ensure that `pushViewController` will generate my custom nav bar item?

Comment: Show the code to push controller

Comment: You could try to change approach. Use a normal UINavigationController and then format the navigation bar items as you wish on every push of a new controller. You can do that in every controller or use the UINavigationControllerDelegate – navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:

Comment: Samkit, the code to push the controller is simple: create a new VC from a xib file using initWithNibName, and then [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];

Comment: cescofry, the problem is that the navigationItem property of the pushed VC is of the wrong class: I checked with the debugger, the class is UINavigationItem instead of MyCustomNavigationItem. So clearly, the new VC is showing a default black nav bar item instead of my custom item which contains a custom title view, specialized buttons, etc.... but: only for the SECOND VC... the first VC is showing the correct nav bar item, simply because it's item class is explicitly set in the XIB.